# Java Stream > Is is possible to inline an "orElseGet" into a parent Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I wasn't sure how exactly to frame this question, so bear with me...

**1)** Is there a better (aka more "proper") way to instantiate a `Stream` of optional elements, other than adding `null` and subsequently filtering out `null`'s?

```
Stream.of( ... ,
        person.likesRed() ? Color.RED : null)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
...
```

**2)** Secondly, is there a way to "inline" the following `orElseGet` function into the parent `Stream`/`map`?

```
.map(p -> ofNullable(p.getFavouriteColours()).orElseGet(fallbackToDefaultFavouriteColours))
```

The full (contrived) example:

```
import static java.util.Optional.ofNullable;

public Response getFavouriteColours(final String personId) {
    Person person = personService.findById(personId);

    Supplier<List<String>> fallbackToDefaultFavouriteColours = () ->
            Stream.of(
                    Color.BLUE,
                    Color.GREEN,
                    person.likesRed() ? Color.RED : null)
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(Color::getName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return ofNullable(person)
            .map(p -> ofNullable(p.getFavouriteColours()).orElseGet(fallbackToDefaultFavouriteColours))
            .map(Response::createSuccess)
            .orElse(Response::createNotFound);

}
```

Comment: Nah, this looks about as good as it gets.

Comment: I second that. I can't see any scope of improvement in your current code. This is actually how it could be. However, I think instead of `null`, you may have some DEFAULT/NONE color enum constant instead, but that said it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Did you mean `.orElseGet(Response::createNotFound)`?

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner expression would be

```
Stream.concat(Stream.of(Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN),
              person.likesRed()? Stream.of(Color.RED): Stream.empty())
```

This isn’t simpler than your original expression, but it doesn’t create the bad feeling of inserting something just to filter it out afterwards or, more abstract, of discarding an already known information that has to be reconstructed afterwards.

There is even a technical difference. The expression above creates a Stream that a has a known size that can be used to optimize certain operations. In contrast, the variant using `filter` only has an estimated size, which will be the number of elements before filtering, but not a known exact size.

The surrounding code can be greatly simplified by not overusing `Optional`:

```
public Response getFavouriteColours(final String personId) {
    Person person = personService.findById(personId);
    if(person == null) return Response.createNotFound();

    List<String> favouriteColours = person.getFavouriteColours();
    if(favouriteColours == null)
        favouriteColours = Stream.concat(
                Stream.of(Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN),
                person.likesRed()? Stream.of(Color.RED): Stream.empty())
            .map(Color::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return Response.createSuccess(favouriteColours);
}
```

Even the Stream operation itself is not simpler than a conventional imperative code here:

```
public Response getFavouriteColours(final String personId) {
    Person person = personService.findById(personId);
    if(person==null) return Response.createNotFound();

    List<String> favouriteColours = person.getFavouriteColours();
    if(favouriteColours==null) {
        favouriteColours=new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(favouriteColours, Color.BLUE.getName(), Color.GREEN.getName());
        if(person.likesRed()) favouriteColours.add(Color.RED.getName());
    }
    return Response.createSuccess(favouriteColours);
}
```

though it’s likely that a more complex example would benefit from the Stream API use, whereas the use of Optional is unlikely to get better with more complex operations. A chain of Optional operations can simplify the code if all absent values or filter mismatches within the chain are supposed to be handled the same way at the end of the chain. If, however, like in your example (and most real life scenarios) every absent value should get a different treatment or be reported individually, using Optional, especially the nested use of Optionals, does not improve the code.